# jQuery Mobile Popop Not Hiding or Showing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this as my html;

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="content" class="Content">
        <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Tooltip</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            This is a completely basic popup, no options set.
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When I run my jQuery Mobile app, all the page transitions work great but for some reason the popups are not hidden at startup and hence the anchor link click does nothing.

I am loading these libraries;

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Also, if I run `$('#popupBasic').popup('close');` nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a planned feature for JQM that is not available yet. That feature won't be able to be used till JQM 1.2. Try a plugin like http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/ to provide that functionality.

Comment: My point is why document something that is not available yet? Kinda confusing to say the least

Comment: Notice how it says test in the url.

Comment: Here is where they mention future plans and link to that document you gave in the first comment. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isVisible=$('#popupBasic').is(':visible'); or var isHidden=$('#popupBasic').is(':hidden');
if(isVisisble)
{
 $('#popupBasic').hide('slow');
}
else
{
$('#popupBasic').show('slow');
}
});
```